# Bluetooth headphone manager for Windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, media-manager, bluetooth

The default bluetooth manager for windows (in the control panel) really sucks. Its not easy to reconnect devices, which I frequently need to do when switching from my phone. Are there any alternatives out there?