# Bluetooth manager for Windows

Tags: windows, collection-manager, bluetooth

What is the best Bluetooth management software for Windows (7-10)? The default Bluetooth managers are horrible.

Features I'm looking for:

- (optional) compatibility with Bluetooth-enabled legacy Palm PDA's
- Browse remote devices (similar to ES File manager for android)
- Easily control Bluetooth connections
- List all available device capabilities
- Advanced pairing options
- Transfer files

And yes, I do realize that there is a similar question [already](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19918/bluetooth-headphone-manager-for-windows). However, since it has not received an answer in a sizable amount of time, and it does not meet my specific software criteria, I am asking a more specific question here.